# How to change the pixels in an image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i actually try to do the following: I have loaded an external image in a bitmapdata object and create a bitmap from it which i attach it to a sprite/MovieClip in order to have mouse events on it. Now under the previous logic i loaded two images (let's say circles) of the same size one that has a particular color and is covered by its black foreground circle. When i press left mouse button and hold it down i want while the mouse is moved to erase the foreground circle's pixels and so the background image starting to appear. I tried this to achieve but had no luck. In my best attempt i achieve to draw a line in the foreground image but i cannot reveal the background!

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BlendMode;

    public class Test2 extends MovieClip
    {
        // properties - state

        // to attach the image and have mouse events
        private var frontImage:Sprite;
        private var backImage:Sprite;

        // to load the image
        private var myLoader:Loader;

        // to get the bitmap data of the image
        private var frontBitmapData:BitmapData;
        private var frontBitmap:Bitmap;

        // test
        private var frontMask:Bitmap;

        // constructor
        function Test2():void
        {
            // load the background image            
            backImage = new Sprite();
            attachImageToSprite1(new URLRequest("btest.jpg"));
            backImage.mouseEnabled = false;
            this.addChild( backImage );

            // load the front image 
            frontImage = new Sprite();
            attachImageToSprite2(new URLRequest("test.jpg"));
            frontImage.mouseEnabled = true; // enable mouse
            frontImage.buttonMode = true;   // set button mode 
            this.addChild(frontImage);  // load to stage

            this.frontImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
            this.frontImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        }

        // methods
        private function attachImageToSprite1(Name:URLRequest):void
        {
            this.myLoader = new Loader();
            this.myLoader.load(Name);
            this.myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete1);
        }

        private function attachImageToSprite2(Name:URLRequest):void
        {
            this.myLoader = new Loader();
            this.myLoader.load(Name);
            this.myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete2);
        }

        private function getImageBitmapDataFromSprite(srcImage:Sprite):BitmapData
        {
            var tmpBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(frontImage.width, frontImage.height, true, 0xFFCCCCCC);
            tmpBitmapData.lock();
            tmpBitmapData.draw(frontImage);
            tmpBitmapData.unlock();
            return tmpBitmapData;
        }

        private function isPixelAlpha(bitmapdata:BitmapData):Boolean
        {
            var pixelValue:uint = bitmapdata.getPixel32(mouseX, mouseY);
            var alphaValue:uint = pixelValue >> 24 & 0xFF;
            //var red:uint = pixelValue >> 16 & 0xFF;
            //var green:uint = pixelValue >> 8 & 0xFF;
            //var blue:uint = pixelValue & 0xFF;
            return (alphaValue == 0x00) ? true : false;
        }

        private function deletePixelUnderMouse(bitmapdata:BitmapData, bitmap:Bitmap):void
        {
            bitmapdata.lock();
            if ( !isPixelAlpha(bitmapdata) ) {
                bitmapdata.setPixel32(mouseX, mouseY, 0xFF << 24);  // how to make the current pixel's alpha
            }                                                       // equal to zero.
            bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapdata);
            bitmap.x = frontImage.x;
            bitmap.y = frontImage.y;
            this.frontImage.addChild(bitmap);
            bitmapdata.unlock();
        }

        // events
        public function onLoadComplete1(e:Event):void
        {
            frontImage.addChild(this.myLoader.content);
        }

        public function onLoadComplete2(e:Event):void
        {
            backImage.addChild(this.myLoader.content);
        }

        public function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // delete a pixel from the sprite under the mouse
            frontBitmapData = getImageBitmapDataFromSprite(frontImage);
            deletePixelUnderMouse(frontBitmapData, frontBitmap);
            frontImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseDown);
            trace("start");
        }

        public function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            frontImage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseDown);
            trace("stop")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: format your question please. Also, you might be easier off drawing inside a sprite and using that as a mask to get the 'reveal' effect I'm guessing you're after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I got it right, but if you want a 'reveal' effect, as in you draw a mask to display a hidden image for example, this could be achieved slightly easier:

```
var bitmapToReveal:BitmapData = new BitmapToReveal(0,0);
var brush:BitmapData = new Brush(0,0);
var canvasData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bitmapToReveal.width,bitmapToReveal.height,true,0x00FFFFFF);
var cursor:Point = new Point();//used as destination point when painting
var zero:Point = new Point();//reused for painting
var reveal:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapToReveal);
var canvas:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasData);
reveal.cacheAsBitmap = canvas.cacheAsBitmap = true;
addChild(reveal);
addChild(canvas);
reveal.mask = canvas;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, brushDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, brushUp);

function brushDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, paint);
}
function brushUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, paint);
}
function paint(event:Event):void {
    cursor.x = mouseX-brush.width*.5;
    cursor.y = mouseY-brush.height*.5;
    canvasData.copyPixels(brush,brush.rect,cursor,brush,zero,true);
}
```

I'm using two Bitmaps form the library(bitmapToReveal and brush). 
The main thing to look at is the [copyPixels()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) method. I copy
the brush bitmap into the canvas(an empty **transparent** bitmap data),
using the offset cursor position(so the brush centered), and using the 
alpha channel to do that. Note that I've set **cacheAsBitmap** to true
for both mask and maskee. You need to do that to get a transparent mask,
which is key to the effect.

Here is the result:

[image: bitmap brush]

You can 'paint' the mask [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/changePixels/). CS4 Source is [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/changePixels/bitmapPaint.fla).

HTH,
George

Comment: also something else ... could i use another object like a sprite instead of the brush object?

Comment: Of course you can. Easiest way with this setup is to make BitmapData version of your clip using draw() and that should be it...just replace the declaration on line 2 with this:

var brushClip:MovieClip = new SpriteBrush();
var brush:BitmapData = new BitmapData(brushClip.width,brushClip.height,true,0x00FFFFFF);


Alternatively, you could attach the sprite and keep doing something like canvas.draw(brushClip,brushClip.transform.matrix);

This would copy the brush with translation applied to it, assuming you would update it's position to follow the mouse.

Comment: See http://lifesine.eu/so/changePixels/bitmapPaint2.fla and http://lifesine.eu/so/changePixels/bitmapPaint3.fla
Goodluck!

Comment: if i have several different background images of same size and same number of same foreground images that cover them where the images are jpg files what do you suggest?

Comment: not sure I understand. You mean you have different images to reveal, each image having a custom associated 'brush' and you want to have something like layers ? 'different background images' = images to 'reveal' ? - 'same number of foreground images' = custom 'brushes' for each background to reveal ?

Comment: please check my version to see what i want to achieve:

http://www.filesend.net/download.php?
f=c9c21cc5d1be49b6a65eb0779b48692b

but i would like to do it like you way of appearing the background image.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. I got all enthusiastic because I thought you were onto something creative :) Anyway...you need kind of a reverse effect, where your are not reavealing, but hiding/eroding an image to display what's under it. You could achieve it if you draw and copy full values into the alpha channel. I didn't do that, I just used opposite colours for 'lottery ticket scratch' surface and brush, and set an appropiate blend more for the 'scratch surface' to get the thing done quick/cheap :).
Updated fla here: http://lifesine.eu/so/changePixels/bitmapPaint4.fla