# flash: drawing and erasing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm developing a real-time graphical editor for my flash app. In editor T have drawing and erasing tools. Drawing is organized on separate drawingLayer. On mouse move coords are pushed into vector. Finally after user releases mouse, drawing layer is cleared and curve is drawn on display area. Erasing is done in the same way. There's a erasing layer: sprite with `blendMode=BlendMode.ERASE` (display area has `blendMode=BlendMode.LAYER`) added as child to display area. Erasing is ok, I draw curve on erase layer.

But here I have one obvious problem: if there's something on erase layer and I'll draw, erased region will remain erased. So, after I draw something on display layer, I'm trying to draw transparency over it on erase layer:

```
eraseLayer.graphics.lineStyle(thickness, 0, 0);
eraseLayer.graphics.drawPath(....);
```

Still after that erased part of image remains erased. The question is how can I "draw" transparency?

Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** please note that dealing with bitmaps is not an option here, as I'll need to do scaling.

**UPD2:** still erase layer can be bitmap

Comment: Would using BitmapData be helpful in your case ? See this [older answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267454/how-to-change-the-pixels-in-an-image) for an idea. Obviously you can have two small bitmaps - one as a 'brush' and one as an 'eraser'. It might be faster since in the end it's using a single 'canvas' bitmap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! well, using bitmaps will not be good for scaling. Are you trying to tell me that it's imposible to make a region of an image be transparent?

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, it's a bit trickier. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient idea for your setup, but instead of using a layer to erase, could you find the points in the draw list based on a erase coords list and remove them ? Simplest approaches would be to use `indexOf` an pass the point object or the slightly more intensive but flexible approach using distance between points, so you can set a tolerance/threshold for erasing

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza,as far as I understood drawing transparency is possible on Bitmaps. Still bitmaps do not have `blendMode`. Is it possible to draw on erase layer as on bitmap, so that it'll be possible to draw transparency. PS: forgive for bad stated question, can't write it more accurate

Comment: Well, drawing over an erased portion can be done with graphics, but you need another set of draw/erase layers, since you cannot eliminate a portion of graphics directly by altering that move path of yours. Say, if you draw a line 10px wide, then erase it with another 10px wide line to form an uneven "X", then draw a third line through their intersection, you are unable to alter the second line to have skewed edges. Also, you can do it with a Bitmap, just have it being 2x-4x bigger than working area, so one displayed pixel will consist of 4-16 actual pixels.

Comment: @Eugeny89 You wouldn't need a `blendMode` with Bitmaps, you'd simply `copyPixels/fillRect` with transparent pixels (e.g. `0x00FFFFFF`) which should erase existing pixels.